# ngx TranslateService blank page

Tags: angular, typescript

whenever I try to translate angular components using ngx-translate/core by using the translateService in the constructor the page gives me blank

this is appModule :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './layouts/header/header.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './layouts/footer/footer.component';
import { MaintainanceServicesComponent } from './maintainance-services/maintainance-services.component';
import { KelvinatorComponent } from './kelvinator/kelvinator.component';
import { AdmiralComponent } from './admiral/admiral.component';
import { WestinghouseComponent } from './westinghouse/westinghouse.component';
import { Frigidaire2Component } from './frigidaire2/frigidaire2.component';
import { GeneralElectricComponent } from './general-electric/general-electric.component';
import { ContactUsComponent } from './contact-us/contact-us.component';
import { TechnicaArmComponent } from './technica-arm/technica-arm.component';
import { NorgeComponent } from './norge/norge.component';
import { SamsungComponent } from './samsung/samsung.component';
import { DaewooComponent } from './daewoo/daewoo.component';
import { WhirlpoolComponent } from './whirlpool/whirlpool.component';
import { AristonComponent } from './ariston/ariston.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';
import { ZanussiComponent } from './zanussi/zanussi.component';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
// import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LandingPageComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    MaintainanceServicesComponent,
    KelvinatorComponent,
    AdmiralComponent,
    WestinghouseComponent,
    Frigidaire2Component,
    GeneralElectricComponent,
    ContactUsComponent,
    TechnicaArmComponent,
    NorgeComponent,
    SamsungComponent,
    DaewooComponent,
    WhirlpoolComponent,
    AristonComponent,
    AboutUsComponent,
    ZanussiComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      },

      defaultLanguage: 'en'
  })

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}


export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http,'./assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

this is the langingPage component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-page.component.css']
})



export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit {
  HEADERONE:string = '';
  images = true;

   isActive:boolean=false;
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    // this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language
       
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

     // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
    translate.use('en');
}
```

and the en.json file I located in assets/i18n :

```
{
  "HEADERONE": "ORIGINAL SPACE PARTS",
  "HeaderTwo": "PROFESSIONAL DEVICES’ MAINTAINANCE",
  "HeaderThree": "TECHNICAL ACCURACY IN EACH STEP",
  "maintainance services" : "MAINTENANCE  SERVICES",
  "dishwasher":"DISH WASHER",
  "deepfreezer":"DEEP FREEZER<",
  "microwave":"MICROWAVE",
  "washer": "WASHER",
  "fridge": "FRIDGE",
}
```

I don't know what the problem but it doesn't reload any elements of the landing page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use each translate key in Html file like this:

```
{{'HEADERONE'|translate}}
```

also it's better to set `translate.setDefaultLang('en');` and  `translate.use('en');` in app-component.ts

check [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) repository and do step by step.